# What is the correct method for calculating the Content-length header in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, utf-8, express

I'm not at all sure whether my current method of calculating the content-length is correct. What are the implications of using string.length() to calculate the content-length. Does setting the charset to utf-8 even mean anything when using node.js?

```
payload = JSON.stringify( payload );

response.header( 'content-type', application/json; charset=utf-8 );
response.header( 'content-length', payload.length );

response.end( payload );
```

Comment: See this answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17526143/1301058

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Content-Length header must be the count of octets in the response body. `payload.length` refers to string length in characters. Some UTF-8 characters contain multiple bytes. The better way would be to use `Buffer.byteLength(string, [encoding])` from http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html. It's a class method so you do not have to create any Buffer instance.

Comment: This fixed an issue for me where the content-length calculated through responseBody.length has a difference of 1 compared to the content-length header as given in the response.